# How to fetch data from sever if saved in other language?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have an Arabic App when user sign-up I ask hem to choose his service to save service in my DB in the Arabic word **I'm forced to do it**,

So I just Do a switch to compare these services if chooses I just set the state to **English word**  and I have many words "6"

So in the next screen, I get the data from the DB based in service he choice 
in English words because the node name it's saved in **English**

So I don't know if this way is right or not if not tell me what's the best way to handle it without below warning!

but I get this warning after "call updateProviderData() function" to navigating from "services" screen to next screen "Home"

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
>   in the componentWillUnmount method.

Code

```
 updateProviderData = () => {
    this.setState({loading: true});
    const {uid, service} = this.state;
    database()
      .ref(`users/${uid}`)
      .update({
        service,
      })
      .then(async () => {
        switch (service) {
          case 'سباكة':
            this.setState({service: 'Plumber'});
            break;
          case 'الكهرباء':
            this.setState({service: 'Electricity'});
            break;
          case 'دهانات':
            this.setState({service: 'Dyeing'});
            break;
          case 'تلفاز ستالايت':
            this.setState({service: ' Satellite'});
            break;
          case 'التنظيف':
            this.setState({service: 'Cleaning'});
            break;
          case 'المكيفات':
            this.setState({service: 'Air'});
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('logged', "True");
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {
          service
        });
      })
      .then(() => this.setState({loading: false}));
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just save a localization json or xml file with keys and string pairs. Load the localization file based on the language. and load them into a dictionary object and then call this and it will give you the proper word.

This way if you add a new language you just need a new file and don't need to add another switch statement for every language. Also this allows you to update the words in the localization file and they keys never change, In your case your hard coded string are bad as a spelling mistake in one spot can break it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that you should probably handle localization differently.

You are getting the error message specifically because you are calling `setState` on an unmounted component, your "service" component is destroyed when you navigate to "home" when you do:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {
    service
});
```

Specifically, this line is causing the warning:

```
// setState is called after component is unmounted
.then(() => this.setState({loading: false}));
```

Comment: Ouch That's a truth it should call before navigate or don't call it because already it will navigate to new screen "sorry I just thought" , SO Now back to handle localization have any idea to do it in this case?

Answer (score 1):

A method that I've used (before the fancy i18n options) was to just create json files with your translations. The property name is your key that is consistent across your language files. This gives you the ability to just manage one version (say it's English) and then hand that off to whoever translates your stuff. You'll end up with all these json files in a single directory and when your site loads, you can load the specific language based off something like `window.navigator.language`

Example of a faked scenario using a `select` to pick the language you want to work with. The two variables `en` and `fr` is an example of how you would structure your json files.

As far as what to save in your database, I would just store the key and see if that gets you to where you need to be. That way, the key is capable of referencing the right phrase in any of the language you're targeting without any issue. However, there could be extra challenges that come along with this such as getting rid of a key when it still is in the database.

```js
const en = {
  welcomeMessage: 'Welcome to the app'
};

const fr = {
  welcomeMessage: 'bienvenue dans l\'appli'
};

document.getElementById('languageSelector').addEventListener('change', e => {
  switch(e.target.value) {
    case 'en':
      document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerText = en.welcomeMessage;
      break;
    case 'fr':
      document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerText = fr.welcomeMessage;
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="languageSelector">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
</select>

<h1 id="welcomeMessage"></h1>
```

I would recommend looking into a proper i18n solution though. Since, you know, it's 2019.

- (If you're using Angular) https://angular.io/guide/i18n
- (If you're using React) https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-react
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n

Comment: I Will but now i wanna create a JSON file that contain the different language is u write in the example but the switch case should be in JSON file or on my js file "service screen"?

Comment: Sorry man but now as u see I have 6 services so how can I save it in a localized file and then u just have a welcome msg so in ur case don't archive what I need when i use switch! ```const en = {
  Plumber: 'سباكة',
  Electricity: 'الكهرباء',
  Dyeing: 'دهانات',
  Satellite: 'تلفاز ستالايت',
  Cleaning: 'التنظيف',
  Air: 'المكيفات',
};``` and in switch  ```switch(service) {
          case 'en':
            this.setState({service: ???});
        break;```